# How to connect the font in the node js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, fonts

I have a font air.ttf
Inside css file have the following code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'air';
src: url("fonts/air.ttf");
}
```

Machining the link here so (express framework):

```
function rf(link,folder,type)
{
  app.get("/"+link,function(req,res)
  {
    fs.readFile(__dirname+"/"+folder+"/"+link,function(err,data)
    {
      res.set('Content-Type',type;
      res.end(data);
    });
  });
};

rf("fonts/airborne.ttf","css","application/ttf");
```

Chrome displays the error:
**Failed to decode downloaded font: ... air.ttf**

How to fix it???

Comment: Start by fixing the syntax error?

Comment: Also instead of doing this, you can make use of express.static

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, use [express.static](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express.static), because that's literally what it's for.

As for the decode error: the font you're using is mostly likely technically corrupt. Depending on what's wrong, exactly, some applications may not care, but browsers are super panicky about bad fonts: they use the OTS sanitizer to check for even the smallest possible bit of corruption or bad data, and if it finds any, that font will not load.

Grab yourself a copy of [TTX](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools), the font world's utility of choice to turn a binary font into a human readable XML form (and vice versa), and then do a `ttx air.ttf`, and see whether that reports the font as broken. If it does: problem found. If not: put your findings in your question, because proof that the font is fine